# how to add launch parameters to store variables before launch

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to add a way to have launch options such as

python file.py -P 1.0.0.106:7100

if you know of any way to do this please let me know

i have tried to def variable with the parameters with no luck

i come from Java

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: Have you had a look in `sys.argv` ?

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python command-line arguments", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution.

```
def hello(lx):
    print(lx)
    print("Got these arguments")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    args = sys.argv
    hello(args)
# $ python3 thisfile.py a b c
# ['a', 'b', 'c']
# Got these arguments
```

Comment: But please, have a look at the invaluable comments by other users. Welcome to Stack Overflow ... :)